# Ionic - app icon is not updated when deploying debug version on real android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

First, I have prepared an `512x512` icon and placed it in the `resources` folder. After that, I run the command `ionic resources --icon`. Images of various dimensions are generated under `resources/android/icon/`, and `config.xml` at project root is also updated.

I then execute `ionic build android` and `ionic run android` in sequence. Note that I have a real android mobile phone connected. The app is deployed to the device as expected.

However, when I look for my app on my phone afterwards, the app icon is still the default one.

What goes wrong?